# Flickering on NSSearchfield in NSMenu on status menu item

Tags: macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nsstatusitem, nssearchfield

I am developing a menubar application in which i have used serachfield in NSMenuItem on status bar menu . When app launches . if we open first time menu on status bar then Searchfield flickers strangely , after that every time it is ok .

Answer (score 0):

enable layer backed drawing for the NSSearchField